# How to bring values for each ID details in the array?

Tags: php, arrays

I was searching for a solution for my problem.

I have the code below:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultQuery)){
    $response = array(
        'name' => $row['name'],
        'data' => $row['data']          
    );
    $responses[] = $response;
}
echo json_encode($responses);
```

The code  will bring this result:

```
[{"name":"Name001","data":"1"},
{"name":"Name001","data":"2"},
{"name":"Name001","data":"3"},
{"name":"Name002","data":"4"},
{"name":"Name002","data":"5"},
{"name":"Name002","data":"6"}]
```

But I would like to have the result below:

```
[{"name":"Name001","data":[1,2,3]},
{"name":"Name002","data":[4,5,5]}
```

Each "Name" has its own ID, I would like in the "while" put each id with its own data.

Thank you for your help.

## 1. Update:

```
    $id_name = "xx";
    
             while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultQuery)){
    
    if($id !== $row['id']){
                $response = array(
                    'name' => $row['name'],
                    'data' => array($row['data'])         
                );
                $responses[] = $response;
             }
 $id_name = $row['id'];
            }
            echo json_encode($responses);
```

I am trying to check the ID first and if is different will bring to me:

```
[{"name":"Name001","data":["1"]},{"name":"Name002","data":["4"]}]
```

Comment: What? Negative? Why?

Comment: Note that the down-vote indicates: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." It might help if you make an attempt, then show what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: @showdev, Hi, I am trying to bring a ARRAY to each ID that I have I need to bring the data for that ID and at the end build the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultQuery))
    $tmp[$row['name']][] = $row['data']; 

foreach($tmp as $key => $item)
    $responses[] = array('name' => $key, 'data' => $item); 

echo json_encode($responses);
```

result

```
[{"name":"Name001","data":["1","2","3"]},{"name":"Name002","data":["4","5","6"]}]
```

Comment: I would like to say thank you for your time and your patience to understand what I was trying to do. Thank you and have a great day.

Answer (score -1):

I made a test here, hope you like.

```
$arr = array();

$arr[] = array(
  'name' => 'val',
  'data' => array(1, 2, 3)
);

$arr[] = array(
  'name' => 'val',
  'data' => array(1, 2, 3)
);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Output:

```
[{"name":"val","data":[1,2,3]},{"name":"val","data":[1,2,3]}]
```

Comment: Hi Haroldo, how did you get this result? Could you please put your thought? Thank you.